# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Изначально тире было перед всеми "это".

Из этого следует, что данное внедрение — это не процесс одного-двух месяцев, это не какая-то компьютерная система подсчета, не программа, это философия, образ мышления Вас и Ваших сотрудников, если хотите, это Ценность Вашей компании.

Comment: "образ мышления Вас..."=== Лучше так: "образ мышления Ваш и Ваших сотрудников".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы применила единый знак "запятая-тире", чтобы отделить отрицание от утверждения. **Использование нескольких тире затрудняет чтение, они могут восприниматься ка парные знаки:**

Из этого следует, что данное внедрение — это не процесс одного-двух месяцев, это не какая-то компьютерная система подсчета, не программа, — это философия, образ мышления Ваш и Ваших сотрудников, если хотите, это Ценность Вашей компании.

Примечание. Да, "образ мышления Вас" надо исправить.

Comment: Я игнорирую парные знаки в случаях, когда при последовательном прочтении не возникает смыслового разрыва, а вот сдвоенные знаки мне почти всегда мешают: вынуждают анализировать то, что казалось (и не без основания) понятным. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок нет. Есть корявость русского языка.
Грамотно и литературно.
Из этого следует, что данное внедрение не есть процесс одного-двух месяцев, некая компьютерная система подсчета или программа - это философия, Ваш образ мышления и Ваших сотрудников; если хотите - это Ценность Вашей компании.
Точка с зпт. - указать на особенность, смысл и ценность обобщения. Тире в нём - подчёркивает и усиливает смысл обобщения.
Удалил отрицания. Одного в сказемом *не есть - достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

> Из этого следует, что данное внедрение
> — это не процесс одного-двух месяцев,
> это не какая-то компьютерная система
> подсчета, не программа, это философия,
> образ мышления Вас и Ваших
> сотрудников, если хотите, это Ценность
> Вашей компании.

По-моему, лучше разбить на два предложения. Или даже на три.

*Из этого следует, что данное внедрение — это не процесс одного-двух месяцев, это не какая-то компьютерная система подсчета, не программа. Данное внедрение -- это философия, образ мышления Ваш и Ваших сотрудников; если хотите(,/--) это Ценность Вашей компании.*

Answer (score 0):

Я бы добавил второе тире, но убрал бы "это" из первой части (из "этого" следует, ... что "это") и переформулировал спорное выражение "образ мышления вас..." на  "О.М.  - [чей] ваш и ваших сотрудников". Заключительную часть отделил бы точкой с запятой: она идёт "вдогонку", когда внимание читателя уже перегружено, и предлагает альтернативную трактовку ранее сказанному.

Из этого следует, что данное внедрение - не процесс одного-двух месяцев, не какая-то компьютерная система подсчета, не программа - это философия, образ мышления - Ваш и Ваших сотрудников; если хотите, это Ценность Вашей компании.

Comment: @Alex_ander, в предложении " не программа - это философия - искажается смысл. Получается: " то, что является не программой - является философией" поскольку тире между подлежащим и сказуемым имеет характер логического определения. 

>Слава подобрал наилучший вариант, разбив на два предложения.

Comment: Здесь нельзя усмотреть предложения с упомянутыми подлежащим и сказуемым, поскольку до завершения перечисления через запятую однородных отрицаемых сущностей не закончено предыдущее предложение.
Можно было бы на месте этого тире точку поставить (как и перед "если"), но теряется вероятная идея дать "внедрению" определение (это обычно одна фраза).